# Function returning wrong value, in C, using gcc Intel compiler

Tags: c, function

I am writing this because I have really no idea why this is happening. I know how to correct it/go around it but what I would like to know is the reason this occurs. I am using C and my compiler is gcc 4.4.1 (TDM) running on an Intel machine.

Assumptions about floats: -Conform to the IEEE 754 standard
                          - Are stored in a Big Endian way

Let's assume we have a function taking in an array of 4 bytes and returning them as a float. That is the goal of the function. Let's also say that for example all the function will do is get the bytes in the "right order" and since the system is little endian it will just swap them and put them into the float to return a value. For simplicity's sake I don't include any checks for NaN or INF since this is not the purpose of this question.

```
float testFunction(char* arr)
{
    //this will be the float we return
    float ret;

    //let's just get a char pointer to the float so we can alter its byte values
    char* c = (char*)&ret;
    //just swap them so they conform with little endian byte order
    c[0] = arr[3];
    c[1] = arr[2];
    c[2] = arr[1];
    c[3] = arr[0];

    //up to here if you debug and watch ret's value it is correct as it is supposed to be
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is wherever I use the function ... let's say like below

```
   float f = testFunction(arr);
```

Then the float f has a completely irrelevant float value to the bytes you pass as parameters.

The way to succesfully go around this is to declare a function that accepts the float as a parameter and give it a value inside the function like so:

```
void testFunction(char* arr,float* f)
{
   char* c = ((char*)f)
   c[0] = arr[3];
   c[1] = arr[2];
   c[2] = arr[1];
   c[3] = arr[0];
 }
```

But still my question is, why does this happen when I try to return the value? I do understand that float ret is a temporary value inside the scope of the function but the return statement should copy its value outside of the function. Isn't it correct? 
What am I missing? I guess it must be something really obvious.

Comment: What array of bytes are you passing in and what `float` value are you expecting?

Comment: If we consider the `float` to be 32 bits (and `char` to be 8 bits), what you are doing is correct.

Comment: @Charles:  Any array of bytes and I expect the float corresponding to the IEEE 754 standard. Just use any converter to see what you have to give as bytes and what float you should expect. A very nice one is here:

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html

Comment: I've tried your test function and it works ok for me. At least bytes i provided to the function and in the returned float value were the same and have the right order. So try to print the returned value on your machine byte per byte.

Comment: @Lefteris So `arr` is `BigEndian`, right? Because if it's already `LittleEndian` you don't need swapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say something stupid. But try initializing `ret`, like `float ret = 0;`.

I'm not sure you can initialize a variable "piecemail" one `char` at a time and consider it to be "initialized" for the C standard (and the compiler)

Answer (score 4):

Actually in both cases the float should have a "completely irrelevant" value, unless you carefully craft that array of chars (for example `memcpy` from a `float`).

You can't just set the bytes and hope it will magically match the representation on your platform.

Comment: What do you mean? I am assuming a float representation conforming to the IEEE 754 single precision standard stored in little endian format. Can it diverse even further than that?

-And the second case, passing by reference seems to be always working on my system. This is why I have gotten a bit confused

Comment: @Lefteris Let's say this: there are places where there is C and there isn't IEEE 754. When you ask questions about C, it's always better to write at the beginning something like "I need to make this work on gcc (VC++/Intel C compiler) on Intel". In this way no one can throw you "the C Standard doesn't speak about this or that". You then enter the land of "specific platform and specific compiler". To  comprehend how much "general" the C/C++ standards are, read this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.6

Comment: Yes you are right xanatos. I should have specified this. The article you provide is an interesting read. Will spend some time reading it.
But the question still remains, anybody knows why this would be working one way and not the other?

Answer (score 2):

WAG. Because of the typecast, the compiler doesn't recognize that the `f` variable has been updated. For the compiler there's no link between the `f`variable and your `c` pointer. It doesn't know it's an alias.
As in the ABI the float is returned in a register, it should generate a load from the stack when it does the `return`, but as it sees that `f` is unitialized, it does nothing and returns the random content of the register used for that. 
If you declare `float` as `volatile` it should do what you expect.

As said, it's a wild a.. guess.

Comment: IT was a nice guess but unfortunately at least in my system it did not work. Thanks for putting some thought into it though.

Just wondering about two of your abbreviations: WAG - > ?
              ABI -> Application binary interface?

Comment: WAG:wild ass guess   ABI: Application Binary Interface the convention used by the operating system to pass parameters to and from function the compiler has to follow.